# Access the input data of express res.render in jade javascript section

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i had write a node.js application an render a jade page with.

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', inputData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonAll))});
```

now i want to access the inputData within the layout.jade, which is extended by the index.jade

```
script(type='text/javascript').
   function setTextFilter(elem) {
      $('#filter').text(elem.innerHTML);
      var searchElement = $('#searchElement').text();
      var res = [];
      console.log(elem.innerHTML);
      var inputp = !{inputData};   //<--- ERROR here (Unexpected Identifier)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(inputp));
      if(elem.innerHTML == "foo"){
        for(var i = 0; i < inputp.length;i++){
          if(inputp.year == searchElement){
            res.push(allData[i])
          }
        }
        console.log(res);
      }
    }
```

this does not work, I get the error: Unexpected identifier. I found out, its because of the !{inputData} but its the right way to use it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change as below:

```
var inputp = !{inputData};
```

to

```
var inputp = #{inputData};
```

Comment: Thanks, but after doing this, I got Error: inputData not defined.

Comment: You add this code "- var inputp = !{inputData}; " above of "script(type='text/javascript').
   function setTextFilter(elem) {//stmt}" instead of as your code